# Best way to log to Graylog2 from PL/SQL

Tags: logging, plsql, graylog2

What is the preferred way to log to a Graylog2 Server from PL/SQL code?
I couldn't find any PL/SQL Logging API/Package that supports Graylog2.

Comment: [The GrayLog2 documentation](https://www.graylog2.org/resources/documentation/sending/overview) has a bunch of info on how to get data into GrayLog2.

Comment: @Bob I only found an ['Extractor'](https://www.graylog2.org/resources/extractors/544ab9c3e4b02f0fce94254d) for Oracle Database 11.2g.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach would probably be using [UTL_HTTP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_http.htm#ARPLS070) to make calls to the HTTP API of Graylog.  You could also look into making calls to syslog via something like [Log4PLSQL](http://log4plsql.sourceforge.net/) and the forwarding them over using rsyslog.